# Slicing grouped dataframes carries more rows than expected

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, slice

I am trying to filter a dataframe, which has already been produced by a `groupby()`.
An example of the grouped dataframe is below:

```
all_dists          less  more
district answer            
N        yes        9.0   1.0
         no         0.0   0.0
         maybe      0.0   0.0
W        yes        0.0   0.0
         no         0.0   0.0
         maybe      1.0   6.0
S        yes        0.0   0.0
         no         0.0   0.0
         maybe      0.0   0.0
E        yes        0.0   0.0
         no         0.0  15.0
         maybe      4.5   0.0
```

If I filter "yes" and "less" I get the desired result:

```
grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), slice('yes')), 'less']
>>>
all_dists          less  more
district answer            
N        yes        9.0   1.0
W        yes        0.0   0.0
S        yes        0.0   0.0
E        yes        0.0   0.0
```

But if I filter "no" or "maybe", then it will carry the previous row(s) with it:

```
grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), slice('no')), 'less']
all_dists          less  more
district answer            
N        yes        9.0   1.0
         no         0.0   0.0
W        yes        0.0   0.0
         no         0.0   0.0
S        yes        0.0   0.0
         no         0.0   0.0
E        yes        0.0   0.0
         no         0.0  15.0
```

My aim is to calculate summatios in the filtered dataframes, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with slicing.

Help, please ^_^

Comment: Did you try without using the `slice` function?

Comment: Also, is any of your variables defined as `Categorical` ?

Comment: No, it is the product of a ```groupby``` operation.

Comment: Yes, but are any of your group variables defined as `categorical` ?

Answer (score 0):

With the given sample, both  `grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), slice('yes')), 'less']` and `grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), slice('no')), 'less']` gives me the error:

```
UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on levels [1], lexsort depth 0'
```

On the other hand, if I do:

```
grouped_df = grouped_df.sort_index()
```

as should be the case for your data is the outcome of `groupby()`, then

```
grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), slice('yes')), 'less']
```

gives me the whole data frame. If you want to extract one single index level, you may need to do:

```
grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), 'yes'), 'less']
```

which gives:

```
district  answer
E         yes       9
N         yes       0
S         yes       6
W         yes       3
Name: less, dtype: int64
```

Similarly,

```
grouped_df.loc[(slice(None), 'no'), 'less']
```

gives

```
district  answer
E         no        10
N         no         1
S         no         7
W         no         4
Name: less, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks... I understand your point but it still won't work even if I sort index. Peculiar why I do not get the error in any case though.